# SP13 - How to stop sync ListItem[where item is updated] in variation list

Tags: sharepoint-server, splistitem, variations, validation-list-items

I have two sites **"/EN" - (*source*)** and **"/DE" (*target*)**. Where i add ListItem in list on **"/EN"** Site, he go to **"/DE/"**.

I want where i edit the same ListItem in **"/EN"**, content in listItem does not change in **"/DE"**.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Any help, please?